# NPC dialog system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog

I have been working on getting a dialog system to work for the past few days but I am having a few problems with it. The first problem is that I need a button press while the text is being typed to finish immediately before moving onto the next sentence, when I tried it just came out with some weird bugs so I reverted it. The second problem I keep running into is that when I copy the NPC and change the dialog of the second NPC, they both just say what the first NPC's dialog is set to.

Currently, I have a collider around the sides of the player and when the player's side colliders touch the NPC's while the space bar is pressed it triggers the conversation. Here is my code:

Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : Character
{
    public BasicNPCPrototype NPCPrototype;
    private bool nearNPC = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    protected override void Start()
    {
        // This needs to be here because the Override normally would override the Character Start function so we have this here to tell the Character Start function to go
        base.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected override void Update() // Because the parent script (The Character script) is using protected virtual update it will Override the local update function (This one) so you have to write protected override to make sure they both run
    {
        // Call the GetInput Function
        GetInput();

        CheckIfNear();

        // This needs to be here because the Override normally would override the Character Update function so we have this here to tell the Character Update function to go
        base.Update();
    }

    void GetInput()
    {
        // If the player is active (playerActive is a protected bool in the "Character" script)
        if(playerActive)
        {
            // Normalize "direction" so moving in both directions won't speed up the character (May not be nessisary when using Input.GetAxis, Needs testing)
            direction = Vector2.zero;

            // Get the horizontal Axis and put in the X value of "direction"
            direction.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            // Get the Vertical Axis and put in the Y value of "direction"
            direction.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        }    
    }

    // When the players trigger collider touches somthing
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        // Check to see if it has the "NPC" tag
        if(collision.tag == "NPC")
        {
            // Set "nearNPC" bool to tue
            nearNPC = true;             
        }
    }

    // When the players trigger collider exits somthing
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        // Check to see if it has the "NPC" tag
        if (collision.tag == "NPC")
        {
            // Set "nearNPC" bool to false
            nearNPC = false;
        }
    }

    private void CheckIfNear()
    {
        // If nearNPC bool is true
        if (nearNPC == true)
        {
            // If the "Jump" Keybind is press
            if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
            {
                // Call the Speak function in the NPCPrototype script
                NPCPrototype.Speak();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NPC Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BasicNPCPrototype : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    public void Speak()
    {
        // Call the "StartDialogue" function in the DialogueManager and pass in our dialogue variable
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }
}
```

Here's my Dialog Manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitBeforeDisable = 1f;
    public GameObject dialogueBox;
    public Text nameText;
    public Text dialogueText;

    public Animator animator;

    private Queue<string> sentences;

    private bool conversationActive = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //dialogueBox.SetActive(false);
        sentences = new Queue<string>();       
    }

    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {

        if (conversationActive == false)
        {
            dialogueBox.SetActive(true);

            conversationActive = true;

            animator.SetBool("isOpen", true);

            nameText.text = dialogue.name;

            sentences.Clear();

            foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
            {
                sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
            }

            DisplayNextSentence();
        }

        if (conversationActive == true)
        {
            DisplayNextSentence();
        }

    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if (sentences.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(sentence));
    }

    void EndDialogue()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isOpen", false);
        StartCoroutine("DisableDialogueBox");
        conversationActive = false;
    }

    IEnumerator TypeSentence(string sentence)
    {
        dialogueText.text = "";

        foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DisableDialogueBox()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitBeforeDisable);
        dialogueBox.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

I'm realitivly new to coding, if I could get some help that would be great! If you have questions about my question feel free to ask.

Comment: You shouldn't name your fields with leading capitals, `NPCPrototype` looks like a class name. At least you didn't declare it as `BasicNPCPrototype BasicNPCPrototype;` which would be throwing instance-vs-static resolution issues.

Comment: @Draco18s Ok, I'll look into fixing it but can you help?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `NPCPrototype`?

Comment: @Draco18s In the inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You aren't changing your `NPCPrototype` reference

> Where are you setting the value of NPCPrototype? – Draco18s
>
> @Draco18s In the inspector – Ultra Gamer

Because you set it in the inspector (and no where else) it is *never going to change.* If you want the dialog to be from a specific NPC, you need to get the component *from* that NPC when the "am I nearby?" check/collision. eg.:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // Check to see if it has the "NPC" tag
    if(collision.tag == "NPC")
    {
        // Set "nearNPC" bool to tue
        nearNPC = true;
        NPCPrototype = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<BasicNPCPrototype>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, However now both NPC's start on their 2nd set of sentences. So if there were to sets, the first is "Hello, my name is ___" and the second is "I like to go fishing on weekends". Instead of the sets running one after another only the second one plays. Any fix to this?

Comment: You have `if (conversationActive == false)` followed by `if (conversationActive == true)`. Both are being called and is the reason for the `else` keyword's existence.

Comment: Thank you! I have marked your response as correct, I do have one more question for you though. If the text is currently being typed then how would you just instantly complete the sentence first instead of directly moving to the next sentence. So stopping the TypeSentence(string sentence) coroutine and just setting dialogueText.text to the sentence that the coroutine takes in.

Comment: You need to save a reference to the coroutine (`StartCoroutine()` returns it) and call `StopCoroutine()` on it.

Comment: The coroutine is already has a yield return null; Where do I need to put the return and StopCoroutine() ?

Comment: `yield return null;` is what puts the coroutine on *pause* and later resumes at the next instruction. I recommend reading up on [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: Ok, I want a button press while the coroutine is running to stop the coroutine and just set dialogueText.text to the sentence variable. Do you do that by returning and stopping the coroutine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188960/discussion-between-draco18s-and-ultra-gamer).